# Why assign `this` to `self` and run `self.method()`?

Tags: javascript

I'm reading the source from [mongoose](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/master/lib/collection.js#L40)

```
Collection.prototype.onOpen = function () {
  var self = this;
  this.buffer = false;
  self.doQueue();
};
```

I don't understand why the author assigns `this` to `self` and runs `self.doQueue()`. Why not just run:

```
this.buffer = false;
this.doQueue();
```

I'm new to javascript, thanks for help.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're right, in this instance they could have simply used `this`.

The use of `me` or `self` is a bit of a hack to ensure the correct context of `this` is used, as within JavaScript the scope of `this` is variant. If for example you have an event trigger a function within your class, `this` would be different, and wouldn't be your object that houses the function, but instead the object that called the function. To resolve this people often use `me` or `self` to ensure they're referring to the correct object... `this`, as in the actual object.

Answer (score 4):

Just to give more clarity to @richard said earlier,

```
Collection.prototype.onOpen = function () {
  var self = this;
  this.buffer = false;
  this.onclick = function(){
     //do some other operations here
     //if you refer `this` here then, `this` will refer to present function not the above. so to make sure it is referring to exact object people pass this to `me` or `self`   
     self.doQueue();
  } 
 };
```

Comment: you can propose an edit to his answer rather than cluttering up the post, thank you.

Comment: plus 1 for a code example that clearly demonstrates what others have tried to explain. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The only reason you would usually do that is if the call to `doQueue()` is inside a block that will change the value of `this` such as another function.

In this case however it doesn't serve any purpose and was probably a remnant of older code that was not changed back.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the developer wanted consistency, **but failed at doing so**.

Otherwise you'd be using `this` in some functions, `self` in other functions and [a mix of both](https://paste.aeum.net/show/83/) in other functions, depending on where you use the object and if you use nested functions/callbacks.

By [always assigning `this` to `self`](https://paste.aeum.net/show/84/) and then using the latter you have one additional assignment at the very beginning of each function but you *always* use `self` to access the object.

However, what the developer did in the code you posted does not make much sense. He should either use `self` or `this` both times instead of a mix that is not even necessary.

Comment: ... but in the line above he's doing `this.buffer = false;`.

Answer (score -2):

self is a copy of 'this',but it always refer to the right object,and 'this' may not.

Comment: It will unless you create a new function scope.

Comment: This is a pretty *hand waving* answer with no examples and not a *real* explanation.