# This keyword acting weird in javascript

Tags: javascript

Hey guys am new to javascript and am really confused with the use of the keyword "this" in javascript.

The code is

```
 function TestObject() {
        TestObject.prototype.firstMethod = function(){
                  this.callback();
                  YAHOO.util.Connect.asyncRequest(method, uri, callBack);

        }

        TestObject.prototype.callBack = function(o){

          this.secondMethod();
        }
        TestObject.prototype.secondMethod = function() {
         alert('test');
        }
```

I know this refers to the global object ..and here i just need to know what this holds here..Is this acting same as testobject here ?..If no please explain me .

Any help would be appreciated ..Thanks

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+this

Comment: [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10580957/why-assign-this-to-self-and-run-self-method/10581010#10581010

Comment: It's not clear from your code, but it looks like you're trying to define `TestObject` prototype methods within the `TestObject` constructor. I don't think that's how it works.

Comment: @Andy so you say this here denotes the TestObject right ?

Comment: Yes. It will do once you've sorted out the code. [Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EfLbG/1/).

Comment: actualy why its necessary to use this ..is it importand to use this keyword  in this case ?

Comment: Is it necessary to use this in this case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include more code for us to be able to see where the `this` value comes from, specially because `this` is a reference to the function's invocation context, so if you don't show us where you invoke those functions, we won't be able to tell you what u'll get. Here is an explanation of `this`:

This refers to the execution context of the function, and it can take 4 type of values, depending on how you invoke the function.

Global invocation: The function is invoked as a global function

```
function global () {
  return this; 
}

global(); // Global object
```

Method invocation: The function is invoked as a method of an object

```
myobject.method = function () {
  return this;
}

myobject.method(); // returns myobject
```

Constructor invocation via the `new` operator: The function is invoked as a constructor function, the value of this, is the object beign constructed, the object that will be automatically created and returned by the constructor funciton. This is only applied when calling a funciton with the `new` operator, and it's not the only way to create objects in Javascript.

```
function Constructor () {
  this.bla = true;
}

new Constructor(); // returns a new object, which has a property "bla" with the value true
```

Using the call and apply methods of functions: Call and apply let you set the `this` value of the function that will be invoked.

```
myobject = {
  bla = true,
  method = function () {
    return this;
  }
};

function setMe () {
  return this;
}

setMe.call(myobject); // returns myobject
myobject.method.apply(window); // returns window, the global object
```

Answer (score 0):

Scope in javascript is a pain if you come from pure oo language where this refer to the instance/class.

In javascript it's different, you got to pass the context to your callback to ensure you'll remain in your instance/class scope you can do so if using jquery :

remplace:

```
YAHOO.util.Connect.asyncRequest(method, uri, callBack);
```

by

```
YAHOO.util.Connect.asyncRequest( method, uri, jQuery.proxy(this.callBack, this) );
```

Can't explain more i'm at work, but you'll be able to find informations there:
more informations:

[bind vs jquery proxy](http://jsperf.com/bind-vs-jquery-proxy)

[Understanding scope](http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/)

Comment: But indeed you may misunderstand how to prototype in js, i've made up a small example of prototyping if you wish: http://jsfiddle.net/n9PWR/2/